# Using jquery to hide set of <a> tags if no description

Tags: jquery

I am trying to hide  tags when they have no text description, for a set of dynamically generated links. Usually this won't be necessary as links that don't have text to click on will not be visible anyway. But the page uses a stylesheet which assigns borders to each of these links. So my aim is to hide these links unless they contain clickable text (because their borders are visible)

I need a formula to target the text in the a tag - to say if the  tag has no text example ->   [a href=""] ...?..[/a]    then it should be hidden.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".l3_subMenu  > a").hide();
  $(".l3_subMenu > a").each(function(i) {
    if ($(".l3_subMenu > a") == '') {
      $(".l3_subMenu > a").show();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
l3_subMenu a {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: inline;
  padding: 0.4em 2em 0.4em 2em;
  margin-left: 1em;
  line-height: 3.0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="L3Links l3_subMenu">
  <a href="#Section1Title">Pre employment checks</a>
  <a href="#Section2Title">&nbsp;</a>
  <a href="#Section3Title">&nbsp;</a>
  <a href="#Section4Title">&nbsp;</a>
  <a href="#Section5Title">&nbsp;</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Why aren't you using the `each` parameter `i`

Comment: So you want to hide links that has no TEXT?

Comment: Inside the `each` use either `this` `i` or the second param `e` https://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".l3_subMenu  > a").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().trim() == "" 
  }).hide()
});
```

It will hide all Links that is empty, aka contains no text.

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".l3_subMenu  > a").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().trim() == "" 
  }).hide()
});
```

```css
l3_subMenu a {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: inline;
  padding: 0.4em 2em 0.4em 2em;
  margin-left: 1em;
  line-height: 3.0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="L3Links l3_subMenu">
  <a href="#Section1Title">Pre employment checks</a>
  <a href="#Section2Title">&nbsp;</a>
  <a href="#Section3Title">&nbsp;</a>
  <a href="#Section4Title">&nbsp;</a>
  <a href="#Section5Title">&nbsp;</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest each and toggle

```js
$(function() {
  $(".l3_subMenu  > a").each(function() {
    $ele = $(this);
    $ele.toggle($ele.text().trim() !== "");
  });
});
```

```css
l3_subMenu a {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: inline;
  padding: 0.4em 2em 0.4em 2em;
  margin-left: 1em;
  line-height: 3.0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="L3Links l3_subMenu">
  <a href="#Section1Title">Pre employment checks</a>
  ><a href="#Section2Title">&nbsp;</a><
  ><a href="#Section3Title">&nbsp;</a><
  ><a href="#Section4Title">...&nbsp;</a><
  ><a href="#Section5Title">&nbsp;</a><
</div>
```